# Pygame bad sound quality

Tags: python, pygame

Im trying to play a backround music in pygame but the qualtiy is kinda bad, altough if i play the the mp3 file outside python, for example in vlc, the sound quality is perfectly fine, so there is no issue with the file itself / my headset.
this is the code that i used to play the song:

```
mixer.music.load("song.mp3")
mixer.music.set_volume(0.6)
mixer.music.play(-1)
```

any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able the fix this issue, and it turns out there was no issue with my code.

I did some testing with different `mp4` and `ogg` files, and I have found that, for some reason, if an `mp4` file has very low kpbs rate, then its going to sound weird—although in music players like Groove and VLC it’s going to sound fine—when played in pygame with:

```
mixer.music.load("song.mp3")
mixer.music.set_volume(0.6)
mixer.music.play(-1) # the -1 is just so the song starts to play again, if it finished
```

So what I did is download the song with a higher kbps rate, and the quality instantly got better in pygame / python aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pygame.mixer.init()`

For example:

```py
pygame.mixer.init(44100, -16, 2, 2048) # (frequency, size, channels, buffer)
```

It's possible that a low buffer size is attributing to a poor audio quality. Play around with the values.

Read up on `mixer.init` [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.init)

Comment: didnt fix it:/ there is still a weird background noise